# Reset the password in symfony 2.1 *

Tags: php, symfony-2.1

i want to give change password facility to users.
For authentication, i am using in_memory providers in security.yml file. 
So there is any method to change the username and password.

Answer (score 0):

if it is useful for you, I am using FOSUserBundle which offers to users this facilities. Such us, change password, change profile, email confirmations or register users.

I think this is not available for it. You can check this part of the docs. http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#using-multiple-user-providers